# Speed up copy/pasting across multiple sheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to write code which runs but it's quite slow (takes about 2 minutes atm and the block size is going to increase by 52 soon).  I would like to know if there's a better way to achieve this small section of code.  The code selects 10 sheets simultaneously so that the copy and paste will affect all 10 sheets.  The only copy and paste that I could get to work was the absolute worst version, as you can see, because all the other options I tried only pasted the ranges to a single sheet, not all 10.  Would love to know if it's possible to do better.  I had to activate the first sheet and do the full range.copy, range.select, activesheet.paste!  varray contains 10 sheet names, MaxRngLive is 20, RngLiveRange is a 1 dimensional array of 156 columns containing live formulae and RngPasteRange is a 156x156 block into which those formulae will be pasted.  Later in the code, I value out all of the cells in each block except the top row (again using range.pastespecial xlpastevalues!), thus reducing file size by about 75% overall.

```
Sheets(varray).Select

Sheets("c_DAZN.com_GF").Activate

Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(varray(0))


For j = 1 To MaxRngLive
      
    Application.StatusBar = ws2.Name & " " & j
      
    Set RngLiveRange = ws2.Range(Range(RngLiveName).Rows(j))
    Set RngPasteRange = ws2.Range(Range(RngPasteName).Rows(j))
    RngLiveRange.Copy
    RngPasteRange.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
Next j
```

Thanks very much everyone!

Comment: Can't you just copy and paste the entire range instead of doing it row by row?

Comment: It does paste it all at once but the paste destination blocks are 156 x 156 and separated by several rows so that is what the loop does - goes through all 20 of those blocks. RngPasteRange is a 156x156 2d array starting at eg af70, af300, af700, af1000 etc. I probably need to upload more of the code so that it's easier to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. I'm assuming your list of destination sheets is a string

```
Function copyRange(sourceRange As Variant, destRange As String, wks as String)
    arr = Split(wks, ",")
    For Each i In arr
        Worksheets(i).Range(destRange) = sourceRange.Formula
    Next i
End Function

Sub test()
wk = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3" 'Comma separated list of destination sheets
'Tested by selecting the range to be copied, you can define your source range however you want
Call copyRange(Selection, Selection.Address, wk)
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, in my test the destination range is the same as the source range, but you can input whatever destination range you need

Comment: That would be very useful but I can't use the ". Formula" method because it put a load of "@" into my offset and index formulae and then they stopped working. I did originally write it with range =range.formula looping through one sheet at a time but it was much slower than my current version which benefits from only having a total of 20 loops instead of 200 (20 x 10 sheets). I really just want to know if it's possible to have a copy/paste method like range =range.value which can apply to multiple sheets simultaneously for the same range in each sheet. That would be the fastest option, I think

Comment: Assuming your formulas in your source sheet reference locations within this same sheet, do you want your destination formulas to reference these same locations or their corresponding locations on each destination sheet? For example, if I have a formula referencing A1 on my source, do I want the destination formulas each to reference A1 on their respective sheet?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean and the answer is yes, sort of. Copy range will be eg af1:ge1, destination range will then be af1:ge156. Source range is always 1 row by 156 columns, destination range is always 156 x 156 with the first row of destination being the same as source range.

Comment: you could use an intermediate array to restructure the source to the target format before dumping to the sheets. this should solve the overhead. concerning the "@" when using .formula I don't understand? the formulas will be stored in the array cfr. what you have in your source.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it put a load of '@' into my offset and index formulae", and what I meant to ask is, for example if you have a formula in your SourceSheet that references cell `'SourceSheet'!A1`, do you want your copied formula in DestinationSheet to reference `'SourceSheet'!A1` or `'DestinationSheet'!A1`?